# How to display errors from a custom controller in the view cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, messages, global-messages, frontend-error

I've created a custom controller to add multiple items from a grid view to the cart all at one time.

Works just fine - the problem is the success and error messages are not being displayed on the view cart page.

Here is the controller:

```
<?php

    class BigBlockStudios_UpdateCart_ManageController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

        // add multiple products to the cart
        public function multipleProdAddAction() {

            $redirect = isset($_POST['redirect']) ? $_POST['redirect'] : 'checkout/cart';

            $success = '';

            $errors = '';

            $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();

            $items = $_POST['data'];

            foreach($items as $key => $item){

                $sku = $item['sku'];

                $qty = $item['qty'];

                $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);

                if(!$id || $qty <= 0) {

                    unset($items[$key]);

                }else{

                    try {

                        $params = array('qty' => $qty);

                        $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);

                        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

                        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);

                        $success .= $product->getName(). " is successfully added into cart <br />";

                    }catch(Exception $e) {

                        $errors .= $e->getMessage() . '<br />';

                    }

                }

            }

            $cart->save();

            if(strlen($success) > 1) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($success));
            }

            if(strlen($errors) > 1){
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($errors));
            }

            $this->_redirect($redirect);

        } // multipleProdAddAction()

    } // controller

?>
```

The view cart page is displaying messages, if I add an item from a default product page, I get the success message.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you have set the message in `core/session`. Have to set message in `checkout/session` to get it in checkout page.

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($errors));
```

Magento has set the message in checkout session while adding a product to cart.

Refer this [files](https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php#l54-l57)

Comment: ok- perfect - thanks... so hmmm.  you can see that I have a variable on where to redirect the page to. Say I redirected it somewhere else [account/whatever]. is there a global/session? will something like that display errors "anywhere"?